# sed/awk - print text between patterns spanned across multiple lines

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am new to scripting and was trying to learn how to extract any text that exists between two different patterns. However, I am still not able to figure out how to extract text between two patterns in the following scenario:

If I have my **input file** reading:

```
Hi I would like
to print text
between these 
patterns
```

and my expected **output** is like:

```
I would like
to print text
between these
```

i.e. my first search pattern is "Hi' and skip this pattern, but print everything that exists in the same line following that matched pattern. My second search pattern is "patterns" and I would like to completely avoid printing this line or any lines beyond that.

I tried the following:

```
sed -n '/Hi/,/patterns/p' test.txt
```

[output]

```
Hi I would like
to print text
between these 
patterns
```

Next, I tried:

```
`awk ' /'"Hi"'/ {flag=1;next} /'"pattern"'/{flag=0} flag { print }'` test.txt
```

[output]

```
to print text
between these
```

Can someone help me out in identifying how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right idea, a mini-state-machine in `awk` but you need some slight mods as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo 'Hi I would like
to print text
between these 
patterns ' | awk '
    /patterns/ { echo = 0 }
    /Hi /      { gsub("^.*Hi ", "", $0); echo = 1 }
               { if (echo == 1) { print } }'
```

Or, in compressed form:

```
awk '/patterns/{e=0}/Hi /{gsub("^.*Hi ","",$0);e=1}{if(e==1){print}}'
```

The output of that is:

```
I would like
to print text
between these
```

as requested.

The way this works is as follows. The `echo` variable is initially `0` meaning that no echoing will take place.

Each line is checked in turn. If it contains `patterns`, echoing is disabled.

If it contains `Hi` followed by a space, echoing is turned on *and* `gsub` is used to modify the line to get rid of everything up to the `Hi`.

Then, regardless, the line (possibly modified) is echoed when the `echo` flag is on.

Now, there's going to be edge cases such as:

- lines containing two occurrences of `Hi`; or
- lines containing something *before* the `patterns`.

You haven't specified how they should be handled so I didn't bother, but the basic concept should be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and detailed description paxdiablo, your soln. works like a charm :-). In my case, I don't have repeated occurrences of pattern words along the same line nor any words occurring before "patterns". In my scenario, I can always identify the line starting which I would like to discard everything and this line always starts with the same pattern. Thanks again for the response, much appreciated :-)

Comment: A few issues: 1) "^.*Hi" is the same as "Hi" in an RE, 2) You don't need to specify $0 as the third arg for *sub(), 3) You don't need a gsub() when you just want to replace 1 occurrence, and 4) "{ if (echo == 1) { print } }" is equivalent to just "echo" on it's own.

Comment: Ed. Re 1, no, it's not, not when you're substituting - the difference is between subbing just the hi or everything on the line up to and including the hi. Other points are valid though mostly stylistic.

Answer (score 3):

Updated the solution to remove the line "patterns" :

```
$ sed -n '/^Hi/,/patterns/{s/^Hi //;/^patterns/d;p;}' file
I would like
to print text
between these
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Hi /!d;s//\n/;s/.*\n//;ta;:a;s/patterns.*$//;tb;$!{n;ba};:b;/^$/d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set a flag (f) when you find+replace Hi at the start of a line, clear it when you find patterns, then invoke the default print when the flag is set:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^Hi /,""){f=1} /patterns/{f=0} f'  file
I would like
to print text
between these
```