# Print all line between the search pattern into different files using perl or any method

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed, awk

Could someone help out on this
I want to print all line between the search pattern (`START` & `END`) to different files (`new_file_name` can be any incremental name provided)

But the search pattern repeats in file hence each time it finds the pattern it should dump the line b/w them into different files

The file is something like this

```
START --- ./body1/b1
##########################

123body1
abcbody1

##########################
END --- ./body1/b1

START --- ./body2/b2
##########################

123body2
defbody2

##########################
END --- ./body2/b2
```

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023595/sed-awk-print-text-between-patterns-spanned-across-multiple-lines?rq=1 might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perl solution,

```
perl -MFile::Basename -MFile::Path -ne '
  ($a) = /^START.+?(\S+)$/;
  $b = /^END/; 
  $a..$b or next; 
  if ($a){ mkpath(dirname $a); open STDOUT,">",$a; }
  $a||$b or print;
' file
```

Comment: What if i have " START --- ./body1/b1 " instead of "START --- ./body1 "  then how can we dump into "body1_b1"  file name

Comment: Hi mpapec,it worked, but that was just an examaple hat if i have multiple hier like " START --- ./body1/b1/bb1/bbb1 "  How to tackle this or what needs to be changed in the above script each time based on hierarchy

Comment: @Jamesbond - I'm just curious: do you understand that perl script? Could you enhance or otherwise modify it in future if you had to?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my *awk* solution:

```
# print_between_patterns.awk
/^START/ { filename = $NF ; next } # On START, use the last field as file name
/^END/ { next }                    # On END, skip
{ print > filename }               # For the rest of the lines, print to file
```

Assume your data file is called `data.txt`, the following will do what you want:

```
awk -f print_between_patterns.awk data.txt
```

## Discussion

- After the script ran, you will have `./body1`, `./body2`, and so on.
- If you don't want to skip the BEGIN and END parts, remove the `next` commands.

## Update

If you want to control the output filename in a sequential way:

```
/^START/ { filename = sprintf("out%04d.txt", ++count) ; next }
/^END/ { next }
{ print > filename }
```

Comment: HI Hai Vu, it worked and creatd file names with ./body2 ./body1 but instead if i have  something like ./body1/heat inteasd of ./body1 in the file then in that case the ./body1/heat file doesn't get created. Do we need to add an argument the above script u provieded

Answer (score 1):

To get automatically generated incremental file names:

```
awk '
/^END/   { inBlock=0 }
inBlock  { print > outfile }
/^START/ { inBlock=1; outfile = "outfile" ++count }
' file
```

To use the file names from your input:

```
awk '
/^END/   { inBlock=0 }
inBlock  { print > outfile }
/^START/ {
    inBlock=1
    outdir = outfile = $NF
    sub(/\/[^\/]+$/,"",outdir)
    system("mkdir -p \"" outdir "\"")
}
' file
```

The problem @JamesBond was having below was that I wasn't escaping the "/" within the character list in the sub() so I've updated my answer above to do that now. There's absolutely no reason why that should need to be escaped but apparently both nawk and /usr/xpg4/bin/awk require it:

```
$ cat file
the
quick/brown
dog

$ gawk '/[/]/' file
quick/brown

$ nawk '/[/]/' file
nawk: nonterminated character class [
 source line number 1
 context is
         >>> /[/ <<< ]/

$ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '/[/]/' file
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk: /[/: [ ] imbalance or syntax error  Context is:
>>>     /[/     <<<
```

and gawk doesn't care either way:

```
$ gawk --lint --posix '/[/]/' file
quick/brown

$ gawk --lint '/[/]/' file        
quick/brown

$ gawk --lint --posix '/[\/]/' file
quick/brown

$ gawk --lint '/[\/]/' file        
quick/brown
```

They all work just fine if I escape the backslash without putting it in a character list:

```
$ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '/\//' file    
quick/brown

$ nawk '/\//' file             
quick/brown

$ gawk '/\//' file
quick/brown
```

So I guess that's something worth remembering for portability in future!

Comment: Hello Ed, when using the first script getting this error "awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: bailing out near line 3"   when sourced second one getting 
"Unmatched '. "

Comment: See my earlier comment to you in the thread below anubhava's answer about you using old, broken awk.

Comment: Yeah i did saw so i there any other way i can install or any other workaround for awk

Comment: the first one worked but the second one didn't work. other query on the was cant we have the start/end line also appended within the files

Comment: Of course, just re-arrange the 3 blocks of code so the START comes first and the END last. In what way did the second one "not work"? I already told you how to work around your old, broken awk problem.

Comment: Yes i did change the awk version as u said it worked for 1st one not for the second as it errored out "Unmatched '. "

Comment: Are you SURE you did a copy/paste of the script and didn't try to re-type it yourself? There's no reason for that script to produce an error about unmatched '. copy/paste the window where you execute the script you're running and the error message you get into your original question if you'd like help debugging it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35404/discussion-between-james-bond-and-ed-morton)

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'sub(/^START/, ""){out=sprintf("out%d", c++); p=1}
     sub(/^END/, ""){print > out; p=0} p{print > out}' file
```

This will find and store each match between `START` and `END` into separate files named `out1`, `out2` etc.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, it didnt work as expected and errored out awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: What is your awk version? Run `awk --version`

Comment: Then it should work as I'm not using any awk 4+ specific feature.

Comment: @Jamesbond Any time you get that error message it means you are using old, broken awk which infuriatingly is the default awk on Solaris. Use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk or gawk instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it in Bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || {
    echo "You need Bash to run this script."
    exit 1
}

shopt -s extglob || {
    echo "Unable to enable extglob shell option."
    exit 1
}

IFS=$' \t\n' ## Use default.

while read KEY DASH FILENAME; do
    if [[ $KEY == START && $DASH == --- && -n $FILENAME ]]; then
        CURRENT_FILENAME=$FILENAME
        DIRNAME=${FILENAME%%+([^/])}
        if [[ -n $DIRNAME ]]; then
            mkdir -p "$DIRNAME" || {
                echo "Unable to create directory $DIRNAME."
                exit 1
            }
        fi
        exec 4>"$CURRENT_FILENAME" || {
            echo "Unable to open $CURRENT_FILENAME for output."
            exit 1
        }
        for (( ;; )); do
            IFS= read -r LINE || {
                echo "End of file reached finding END block of $CURRENT_FILENAME."
                exec 4>&-
                exit 1
            }
            read -r KEY DASH FILENAME <<< "$LINE"
            if [[ $KEY == END && $DASH == --- && $FILENAME == "$CURRENT_FILENAME" ]]; then
                break
            else
                echo "$LINE" >&4
            fi
        done
        exec 4>&-
    fi
done
```

Make sure you save the script in UNIX file format then run it as `bash script.sh < file`.

Comment: A shell is an environment from which to call tools. It has programming language constructs to let you sequence calling those tools. It is not intended to itself be a tool for things like parsing text files - there are other tools for that, e.g. awk, perl, etc. If you doubt that, compare the length and complexity of the above shell script to the scripts written in the tools designed to do this job.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry but I have to disagree with that. That may apply to other shells but not generally on Bash. Each tool including Bash has its strengths and weaknesses and it's anyone's option to make the best use out of it. I actually could have used awk for this, unfortunately it seems that it has also been a requirement by the OP to create a directory if doesn't exist which could be still possible in Awk but could be a dirty solution after all awk can only accept a single argument and reinterpret it for that command which causes syntax errors sometimes.

Comment: I agree that each tool has it's strengths and weaknesses. Parsing text files is, by design, a strength of awk and a weakness of shell. Manipulating files and processes is, by design, a strength of shell and a weakness of awk. Therefore parse text files with awk and manipulate files and processes with shell. When you need to do both things, just use both tools, each for the appropriate part of the problem. The above shell script is 5 times the size and much more complex than the awk+shell script I posted to do the same job. QED?

Comment: In a command like system("echo \"" something "\"). If 'something' turns out to have a value that has a ", it would cause syntax error to the called sh. And that's only the basics of it. There are many possible unseen troubles because of this unlike in Bash where you could do "${VAR[@]}" and certainly the arguments would be passed the way they are whatever they may be. One quick solution is to replace ["`$\] with their quoted forms but that's only for a single argument. How about multiple arguments? If you're using Bash you wouldn't even have to go with the trouble.

Comment: You can't simply replace chars with their quoted form as they may already be quoted in the input. If you actually had problematic characters in your file names then you'd still use awk to parse the input files but pipe the awk output to shell to create the output files/dirs rather than simply calling shell via system() or otherwise handle it with an appropriate mix of shell and awk. Either way, it does not make sense to parse the input file with bash. You did remind me to quote the directory name in my script though so thanks for that!

Comment: Piping the output to the shell would still be the same and you're already using two process just to make one task work. Anyway we have our ways and opinions. If you think bash musn't be used with text parsing then it's up to you. But clearly awk has a flaw and care is really needed when passing arguments to an external command. By the way can you give an example source for output where chars in a string to be passed as an argument is already quoted? Cause I don't think there is, and awk doesnt quote it by default. With user data probably although it's a very uncommon practice.

Comment: User data is what I'm thinking of and yes, it's uncommon but so is having quotation marks, etc. in a file name. Yes, one more process will be used instead of writing more than (since without more code the above shell script doesn't handle these edge case either) 5 times the code which is absolutely worth the tradeoff. We'll just have to agree to disagree and people reading this can form their own opinion of the right approach.

Comment: By the way, piping the output to shell would not be the same as invoking shell from awk via system() since awk would print the file names as-is to stdout and then shell can read/use them exactly as if it was reading them from the input file so shell is dealing with the characters that are problematic to shell, not awk.

Comment: If the shell would do a trick reading the arguments line by line the read command, it won't have a problem but if the shell would read it as a script then there would be the same problem. Commands even with other languages like C always call other binaries with separate argument strings, so it's wrong for awk to call a process with arguments separated from one string only. And trying to make the shell 'read' the arguments by lines is already a hack. e.g. Trick: print dirname | "bash -c \"read && mkdir -p \\\"$REPLY\\\"\""

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to see [this](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/extracting-range-of-lines-in-perl.html).

```
perl -lne 'print if((/START/../END/) and ($_!~/START/ and $_!~/END/))' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
START --- ./body1
##########################

123body1
abcbody1

##########################
END --- ./body1

START --- ./body2
##########################

123body2
defbody2

##########################
END --- ./body2
> perl -lne 'print if((/START/../END/) and ($_!~/START/ and $_!~/END/))' temp
##########################

123body1
abcbody1

##########################
##########################

123body2
defbody2

##########################
>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but how can we dump them into different files each

Comment: just a side note, `$_!~/START/` => `!/START/`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
csplit -z file '/^START/' '{*}'
```

Files will be named `xx00 xx01 xx..`

Comment: What if i have " START --- ./body1/b1 "  instead of "START --- ./body1 "