# Using regex for multiple line pattern in shell script

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I've seen the following stackoverflow [How to use regex for multiple line pattern in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808240/how-to-use-regex-for-multiple-line-pattern-in-shell-script) but it doesn't do exactly what I want. I'm looking for a terminal based way of doing an in-place `sed` (or `perl`) regex that will auto change some files for me. (I can probably do it with xml libraries/etc., but I would prefer to use the terminal).

The file I have

```
Some text
<div class="firstClass secondClass" something="else">
    Some random stuff
</div>
Random Text
<div class="thirdClass fifthClass" something="else">
    Some random stuff
    < is something
    < but not /> This
</div>
<div class="fourthClass">
    Some random stuff
</div>
Final Text
```

I tried to do an arbitrary enough example to show a few different use-cases.
I'm trying to convert it into something like the following:

```
Some text
<!-- firstClass start -->
    Some random stuff
<!-- firstClass end -->
Random Text
<!-- thirdClass start -->
    Some random stuff
    < is something
    < but not /> This
<!-- thirdClass end -->
<!-- fourthClass start -->
    Some random stuff
<!-- fourthClass end -->
Final Text
```

I am trying the following code:

```
sed -n '/<div class="\([^ "]*\)[^>]*>/,/<\/div>/{s/<div class="\([^ "]*\)[^>]*>/<!-- \1 start -->/;/<\/div>/d;p}' file
```

but since in the previous stackoverflow question the person didn't want the final line, the answers deleted it, which is not what I want. As can be seen, I want that first text repeated before and after the inside contents.

The regex above properly fixes the first line (changes the div to a comment), but I can't seem to replicate that below the text. I tried to mess around with the regex expression, but I can't seem to get it to work. It's additionally cutting out the very first line and the last lines although I'd like to keep them. Any ideas how to do something like this?

(PS, yes, I know we need `sed -i` for an in-place command, but I want to test it out before I actually run through with it for obvious reasons)

**Edit:** A little addendum as to the idea of what I'm trying to do. Although the above is HTML, this code is not necessarily exclusively for HTML (hence why I don't want HTML/XML processing). The idea is:

```
Some random text before my pattern
PATTERN "info ...
  random stuffs
END PATTERN
Some random stuff after pattern
```

I'd like this to be converted to

```
Some random text before my pattern
NEW PATTERN - info 
  random stuffs
END NEW PATTERN - info
Some random stuff after pattern
```

So no html necessarily. Just something that takes a pattern above some text, replicates it below. The only condition is that `random stuffs` will not have the text `END PATTERN` and so that's what I want to base it off of. `random stuffs` will 100% never ever have the `END PATTERN` text. There's no nesting involved nor any edge cases. It's always the same pattern as shown above. The only "edge" case is that the first line `PATTERN "info ...` might have some extra text up until a line break which I don't care about. That can *always* be deleted. I only care about the word `info` (aka up until the first space character or first `"` character.)

Comment: That's deep in HTML processing and, of course, you _want_ a library.   For example, [Mojo::DOM](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/DOM) is great while I've used [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) nicely as well.  Then, you'll want to articulate your requirements as precisely as possible. (Always/only `div` elements? Any nesting? ...)

Comment: No nesting, always div. The problem is that it's only "html" processing because the example I gave uses `<div>` instead of `##some` or some other string. Which is why I want to stay away from HTML processing. I want to use this with things *other* than html as well. I'll try and add an addendum with a little more about the idea.

Comment: "_...it's only "html" processing because the example I gave uses `<div>` instead of `##some` or some other string._"  -- huh?  But you want to capture between `<div>` and `</div>` tags? Call it whatever but that's structured text.  How does it go with "_##some_" ?  Whats' the closing element?  It'd better be some known format where you can use libraries or you'll have to write a parser and it won't be a one-liner I'm afraid.  (Unless you actually have a trivial case of `start`--`text`--`stop`)

Comment: "_add an addendum with a little more about the idea_" -- by all means, since what you posted now is crystal clear: use HTML parser (and specify the problem better if you want answers).  But, again, I suggest to try to be specific.  What you mentioned in a comment is very open-ended

Comment: If you are certain that it's dirt simple (no nesting, known start-stop tags, no edge cases, etc) then state that clearly.  In that case, yeah you can have a simple regex, if that's _really_ all there is to it.

Comment: I tried to state it clearly. I've added an addendum to hopefully clarify. I guess I don't understand where the confusion is lying. The text between the patterns will 100% not have that pattern. There are no edge cases.

Comment: I tried to add extra info. Hopefully it's more clear? Sorry for not being very clear. It's hard to know what people will assume/not assume. If there's still confusion let me know and I'll try and address it.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Have to go right now, but here's a comment -- for `<div class="X text </div` to be replaced by `<!-- X start --> text <!-- X end -->` one can sure write a simple regex, if patterns are fixed.  But `pattern - info text end pattern - info` is entirely different.  Can't have one regex that'll capture both and others in between. Not even a grammar would cut it.  I'd say that you have to be more precise with what you want. As for the original question, yeah you can have that but it will crucially rely on `<div ... </div>`, of course.  The solution won't work for `X ... end X`.

Comment: No worries. Take your time.
I don't understand how the two are different? If the `pattern` is `<div class=` and the `end pattern` is `</div>` that looks identical. So I don't understand how they are "entirely different"? By `PATTERN` I don't mean some regex, I mean some fixed text that can be repeated. For example, `<div` would be the `PATTERN` in the first example. Can you explain why/how the two are different?

Comment: OH! I think I get what you mean. Yes, it should work *uniquely* for `<div ... </div>`. Basically I would need one command for *each* pattern I want to use it for. (So there would be multiple commands, not just 1 that handles all of them). Is that what you meant? (That's exactly what I wanted. A different command for *each* pattern, so that would be perfect.) 
I keep trying to mess around with it and I can't seem to understand the sed docs in order to make it work.

Comment: At a glance, it sounds like you want `perl -0777pe'...'`, which will cause the entire file to be treated as one line (set `$_` to the entire file).

Comment: Regarding "yes, I know we need sed -i for an in-place command" -that's not REALLY editing the file in-place, it's using a temp file internally. You can alternatively do `cmd '..' file > tmp && mv tmp file` with any command, including sed, and other tools have other ways of updating the input file.

Comment: "_need one command for each pattern_" -- yes, something like that, that's what I meant.  Perhaps one can have a variable for a pattern (see my answer), but that won't work with any and all patterns.  Still, it may help with many simpler ones.

Comment: Let me know if you want to remove our extensive early comments, to clean up this thread.

Comment: It's probably ok to leave them. Keeps track of history and stuff =) I'm going to test out the code now and see if it works. Thanks for all the help earlier. (Sorry for the delay)

Comment: Welcome, let me know if questions come up.  I added to my answer  links to documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, here is a simple take that works in my tests on the particular posted text

```
s{<div\s+ class="(\S+) (.*?) </div>}{<!-- $1 --> $2 <!-- $1 end -->}sxg;
```

The modifiers are: `s` so that `.` matches a linefeed as well (normally it doesn't), `x` so that literal spaces are ignored, what helps readability, and `g` so that this keeps going through the string, matching-and-substituting.

I'd recommend a program in a file for this, not a command-line one ("one-liner"), but since that was specifically asked for in the question here

```
perl -0777 -wpe'
    s{<div\s+ class="(\S+) (.*?) </div>}{<!-- $1 --> $2 <!-- $1 end -->}sxg'
```

The `-0777` switch makes it read the entire file into the `$_` [variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_), which is default for many things in Perl -- regex's `s{}{}` operator in this case.  See [switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches).

---

In a larger and more structured program you could perhaps have beginning and end patterns in variables, for

```
s{$pbeg (.*?) $pend}{...}sxg
```

where for this case it would be

```
my $pbeg = qr{<div\s+ class="(\S+)};
my $pend = qr{</div>}
```

However, this could turn unwieldy if those patterns get complex/

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^<div class="([^ "]*).*/{
          s//<!-- \1 start -->/;h;:a;n;/^<\/div>$/!ba;g;s/\bstart/end/}' file
```

Match a start div.

Manipulate that line into the desired format and make a copy.

Print/fetch the next line until the ending div.

Replace that line with the copy and replace `start` with `end` and print the result.

Repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to [match()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions) and [strongly typed regexp constants](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants) on your first example:

```
$ cat defs1.awk
BEGIN {
    begReg = @/<div\s+class="([^" ]+)/
    endReg = @/<\/div>/
    begFmt = "<!-- %s start -->"
    endFmt = "<!-- %s end -->"
}
```

```
$ cat common.awk
match($0,begReg,a) {
    key = a[1]
    $0 = sprintf(begFmt,key)
}
match($0,endReg,a) {
    $0 = sprintf(endFmt,key)
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f defs1.awk -f common.awk file1
Some text
<!-- firstClass start -->
    Some random stuff
<!-- firstClass end -->
Random Text
<!-- thirdClass start -->
    Some random stuff
    < is something
    < but not /> This
<!-- thirdClass end -->
<!-- fourthClass start -->
    Some random stuff
<!-- fourthClass end -->
Final Text
```

and for your second example we just need a new definitions file but can reuse `common.awk` from above:

```
$ cat defs2.awk
BEGIN {
    begReg = @/PATTERN "([^" ]+)/
    endReg = @/END PATTERN/
    begFmt = "NEW PATTERN - %s"
    endFmt = "END NEW PATTERN - %s"
}
```

```
$ awk -f defs2.awk -f common.awk file2
Some random text before my pattern
NEW PATTERN - info
  random stuffs
END NEW PATTERN - info
Some random stuff after pattern
```

Note we just define in the `BEGIN` sections in the 2 `defs*.awk` files the desired input regexps and output format, we don't change the rest of the code in `common.awk`. All that depends on is that you can define the first capture group in the regexp that matches your beginning delimiter to contain the key info you want retained/printed in the begin and end lines.

You don't strictly need `match()` for the endReg match, but I used it in case you need to tweak it for other ending delimiter formats in future.

Just change `awk` to `awk -i inplace` to do the same pseduo-inplace editing that all the other tools do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Awk script which extracts the first token after `class="` and uses that in the replacement text.

```
awk '/<div class="/ { sub(/.*<div class="/, ""); sub(/[" ].*/, "");
    class=$0; print "<--", class, "start -->"; next }
  /<\/div>/ { print "<--", class", "end -->"; class=""; next }
  1' file >new
```

There is nothing "multi-line" here in terms of regex matching, just a simple facility for remembering some state between lines. Awk is still examining one line at a time (though it's not hard to change that either if you need to; see `RS`).